# Make a filter for WooCommerce Order Search

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In WP I have a WooCommerce order database of about 35k orders. The wp_postmeta table is about 2 million records because all order data is stored as metadata. Therefore the order search is quite slow.
I changed the default wc order search to only search specific metadata fields with this snippet:

```
function custom_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields( $search_fields ) {

    // error_log( 'currently searching in these order fields: ' . print_r($search_fields, true) );
    unset( $search_fields );
    $search_fields[] = '_order_key';
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_company';
    $search_fields[] = 'serialnumbers';
    $search_fields[] = 'information';

    // error_log( 'now only searching in these order fields: ' . print_r($search_fields, true) );
    return $search_fields;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields' );
```

So the wc order search now only searches these 4 types of metadata, but is still quite slow because of the large size of some of them.

I'd like to extend the wc order search with a dropdown filter 'orderkey, company, serials, info' so the search only searches for the metadata key selected in the dropdown. So if I select 'serialnumbers' in the dropdown, the wc order search will only look for my searchterm in the metadata serialnumbers and not in the others. Not only for speed but also for usability.

I'm not really a programmer so help is much appreciated!

Comment: I believe next answer is very close to what you are looking for [Filter orders by specific meta fields in WooCommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210564/11987538) 
get started with it, if you can't figure it out, please adjust your question if necessary. Regards

Comment: Thanx a lot for the quick reply! That answer is really close and usefull. It adds a dropdown to filter the orders. I think the last optional part is where the search is limited to only the metadata that is set in the filter dropdown. I'll check it out, thanx.

Comment: The last optional part where the extra meta keys are added to the search is not exactly what I need, because it adds al the defined meta keys that populate the dropdown filter. I only want the meta key that is selected from the dropdown to be added to the search. (Because I unset the search meta_keys and the added meta key is the only thing the search is looking at.)

Comment: Well, as I indicated before, get started with the code from Loic and if you can't figure it out, please adjust your question. It is true that answers that (partly) lead to a solution during your search certainly deserve an [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), in the end, all the info you can find here is free and an upvote is a token of appreciation.

Comment: Already upvoted, the answer was really helpfull and I appreciate the help! I'll reply my own post with the solution I worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for the help! In [Filter orders by specific meta fields in WooCommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210564/11987538) a similar problem was addressed. A custom filter was made to filter orders by meta key. The last (optional) part was to add all the meta keys from the filter to the search query.
I changed that last part to the snippet below. I now look for the selected value and if it's set I unset the order search and then only add the selected meta key from the dropdown. In the case below the search only searches for the 1 selected meta key. If nothing is selected it uses the default search.

```
//  Make only the selected custom meta field searchable from the admin order list search field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'shop_order_meta_search_fields', 10, 1 );
function shop_order_meta_search_fields( $meta_keys ){
    $filter_id = 'filter_shop_order_by_meta';
    if ( isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && ! empty($_GET[$filter_id]) ) {
        unset( $meta_keys );
        $meta_keys[]   = $_GET[$filter_id];
    }
    return $meta_keys;
}
```

Note: the the above snippet only works in combination with the rest of the code from the other topic to make the filter that's used in this snippet.