# Filter orders by specific meta value that does not match specific strings in Woocommerce admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a filter on the order list based on a specific meta key + value. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210564/3730754) and it helped tremendously. However, I need to create a filter that fits this rule: Show orders that have meta key: '_created_via' with a value that is NOT 'admin' or 'checkout'.

Is there a way to filter `meta_value` with not match specific strings?
See: `$vars['meta_value'] = <NOT 'checkout' or 'admin'>`

```php
// Process the filter dropdown for orders
add_filter( 'request', 'process_admin_shop_order_marketing_by_meta', 99 );
function process_admin_shop_order_marketing_by_meta( $vars ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    
    $filter_id = 'filter_shop_order_by_meta';

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 'shop_order' === $typenow 
    && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && ! empty($_GET[$filter_id]) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = $_GET[$filter_id];
        $vars['orderby']    = 'meta_value';
        if ($_GET[$filter_id] == '_created_via') {
            $vars['meta_value']    = <NOT 'checkout' or 'admin'>
        }
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [`WP_Query` documentation for *"custom field post meta parameters"*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters), you can use `meta_compare` defined to *"NOT IN"* and `meta_value` defined with an *array of values*…

Try the following (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'request', 'process_admin_shop_order_marketing_by_meta', 99 );
function process_admin_shop_order_marketing_by_meta( $vars ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    
    $filter_id = 'filter_shop_order_by_meta';

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $typenow 
    && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && ! empty($_GET[$filter_id]) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = $_GET[$filter_id];
        $vars['orderby']    = 'meta_value';
        if ($_GET[$filter_id] === '_created_via') {
            $vars['meta_compare'] = 'NOT IN';
            $vars['meta_value'] = array( 'checkout', 'admin' );
        }
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

It could work.